# Left Join, storing right-outer values Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, merge, left-join, outer-join

I want to do a merge with left join, but also store the right values that were not merged.

ex.

```
df1:

key1 key2 val1 val2 val3
1     2   
1     1      
2     2        

df2:
key1 key2 val1 val2 val3
1     2    a    b    c
1     1    a    b    c   
3     2    a    b    c
```

what I want:

```
merged
key1 key2 val1 val2 val3
1     2    a    b    c
1     1    a    b    c   
2     2 

saveForLater:
key1 key2 val1 val2 val3
3     2    a    b    c
```

I have tried doing an merge as such:

```
dfStore = pd.merge(dfStore, dfMap, how='outer', on=["key1", "key2"], indicator=True)
```

this then lets me filter on the _merge column but it also gives:
    val1_x val1_y
for each non key column and I'm not sure a nice way to clean that up.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set your key1 and key2 to index , then using `combine_first`, if you need key1 and key2 become column again adding `reset_index()` at the end .

```
df1=df1.set_index(['key1','key2'])
df2=df2.set_index(['key1','key2'])


df1.combine_first(df2.reindex(df1.index))
Out[711]: 
          val1 val2 val3
key1 key2               
1    2       a    b    c
     1       a    b    c
2    2     NaN  NaN  NaN


df2.loc[~df2.index.isin(df1.index)]
Out[712]: 
          val1 val2 val3
key1 key2               
3    2       a    b    c
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed!